# Change the main windows email on windwos phone 8.1

Tags: linked-accounts

When my friend installed her Lumia Phone with windows 8.1 she just created a new account at live.com with some password, she can't remember. The only thing that was correct when she installed it was her name the rest was just gibberish, also the second email she set there for recovery was just fantasy.

Now we wanted to create a real account, so she can install software from the shop, but it seems not possible without reinstalling the whole phone with a new account.

Is there any way to change the main email account in Windows Phone 8.1?

See: [this discussion at answers.microsoft.com/](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpemail/can-i-change-my-microsoft-account-without/4abe33ba-2881-406e-9eb2-32b6dd2a7a54)

Comment: It looks like the question already has a definitive answer at the link you posted. What's the purpose of asking it here?

Answer (score 2):

Per your link, the correct answer is:

> The ONLY way to change the primary Microsoft account that is used on the phone is by hard resetting the phone & setting it up agaib with a different Microsoft account. When you reset the phone the phone will be returned to the state it was in when you bought it. All your personal data and any apos tou installed to the phone will be removed from the phone.

Purchases are always tied to the initial account you set the phone up with, and per your original question, you want to change the account to do this, so you should only need back up any photos taken - you can then go through the initial set-up and create a real account to have the purchases associated with.